# PHP/MySQL allowing current user to edit their account information

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I have created 2 pages

```
update.php
edit.php
```

We start on edit.php so here is edit.php's script

```
<?php
session_start();
$id = $_SESSION["id"];
$username = $_POST["username"];
$fname = $_POST["fname"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$email = $_POST["email"];

mysql_connect('mysql13.000webhost.com', 'a2670376_Users', 'Password') or     die(mysql_error());
echo "MySQL Connection Established! <br>";

mysql_select_db("a2670376_Pass") or die(mysql_error());
echo "Database Found! <br>";

$query = "UPDATE members SET username = '$username', fname = '$fname', 
password = '$password' WHERE id = '$id'";

$res = mysql_query($query);

if ($res)
echo "<p>Record Updated<p>";
else
echo "Problem updating record. MySQL Error: " . mysql_error();
?>

<form action="update.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$id;?>">
ScreenName:<br> <input type='text' name='username' id='username' maxlength='25'   style='width:247px' name="username" value="<?=$username;?>"/><br>
FullName:<br> <input type='text' name='fname' id='fname' maxlength='20' style='width:248px'     name="ud_img" value="<?=$fname;?>"/><br>
Email:<br> <input type='text' name='email' id='email' maxlength='50' style='width:250px'    name="ud_img" value="<?=$email;?>"/><br>
Password:<br> <input type='text' name='password' id='password' maxlength='25'     style='width:251px' value="<?=$password;?>"/><br>
<input type="Submit">
</form>
```

Now here is the update.php page where I am having the major problem

```
<?php
session_start();
mysql_connect('mysql13.000webhost.com', 'a2670376_Users', 'Password') or   die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("a2670376_Pass") or die(mysql_error());

$id = (int)$_SESSION["id"];

$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["username"]);
$fname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["fname"]);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["email"]);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["password"]);


$query="UPDATE members
SET username = '$username', fname = '$fname', email = '$email', password = '$password'
WHERE id='$id'";


mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());
if(mysql_affected_rows()>=1){
echo "<p>($id) Record Updated<p>";
}else{
echo "<p>($id) Not Updated<p>";
}
?>
```

Now on edit.php I fill out the form to edit the account "test" while I am logged into it now once the form if filled out I click on Submit button
and it takes me to update.php and it returns this

```
(0) Not Updated  

(0) <= id of user logged in

Not Updated <= MySql Error from  


mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());
if(mysql_affected_rows()>=1){
```

I want it to update the user logged in and if I am not mistaken in this script it says

```
  $id = (int)$_SESSION["id"];
```

which updates the user with the id of the person who is logged in

but it isn't updating, its saying that no tables were effected

if it helps here's my MySQL Database picture
just click here  http://i50.tinypic.com/21juqfq.png

if this could possibly be any help to find the solution I have 2 more files delete.php and delete_ac.php they have can remove users from my sql database and they show the user id and it works  there are no bugs in this script at all PLEASE DO NOT MAKE SUGGESTIONS FOR THE SCRIPTS BELOW 
delete.php first

```
    <?php

$host="mysql13.000webhost.com"; // Host name 
$username="a2670376_Users"; // Mysql username 
$password="PASSWORD"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="a2670376_Pass"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="members"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// select record from mysql 
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
?>

<table border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<td colspan="8" style="bgcolor: #FFFFFF"><strong><img src="http://i47.tinypic.com/u6ihk.png" height="30" widht="30">Delete data in mysql</strong> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Id</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>UserName</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>FullName</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Password</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Email</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Date</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Ip</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>

<?php
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>

<tr>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $rows['id']; ?></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $rows['username']; ?></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $rows['fname']; ?></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $rows['password']; ?></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $rows['email']; ?></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $rows['date']; ?></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $rows['ip']; ?></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><a href="delete_ac.php?id=<? echo $rows['id']; ?>">delete</a></td>
</tr>

<?php
// close while loop 
}
?>

</table>

<?php
// close connection; 
sql_close();
?>
```

and now delete_ac.php

```
<table width="500" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<td colspan="8" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong><img src="http://t2.gstatic.com/images?           q=tbn:ANd9GcS_kwpNSSt3UuBHxq5zhkJQAlPnaXyePaw07R652f4StmvIQAAf6g" height="30"     widht="30">Removal Of Account</strong> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<?php

$host="mysql13.000webhost.com"; // Host name 
$username="a2670376_Users"; // Mysql username 
$password="javascript00"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="a2670376_Pass"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="members"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// get value of id that sent from address bar 
$id=$_GET['id'];

// Delete data in mysql from row that has this id 
$sql="DELETE FROM $tbl_name WHERE id='$id'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// if successfully deleted
if($result){
echo "Deleted Successfully";
echo "<BR>";
echo "<a href='delete.php'>Back to main page</a>";
}

else {
echo "ERROR";
}
?> 

<?php
// close connection 
mysql_close();
?>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: i will fix security problems once i get the script to work

Comment: Have you tried with $id = $_SESSION["id"]; and not $id = (int)$_SESSION["id"]; in update.php.

Comment: it didnt it gave me () not updated insted of the normal error (0) not updated

Comment: @user1837896 you tried to print `$_SESSION['id']` value. I am sure it is not initialised. Try to print all `$_SESSION` array using this code `print_r($_SESSION);`.

Comment: @user1837896 when are you registering(set) your session? is it really registered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below query, and post output here. Also execute same echo query in phpmyadmin to see what happend.

```
echo $query="UPDATE members
SET username = '$username', fname = '$fname', email = '$email', password = '$password'
WHERE id=$id";
```

From your link it seems anyone can directly go to edit page, that is wrong.

You need to add condition that if user is login then only he can update his profile.

Comment: UPDATE members
SET username = '$username', fname = '$fname', email = '$email', password = '$password'
WHERE id="$id"

Comment: UPDATE members SET username = 'jacob', fname = 'tonna', email = 'email@gmail.com', password = '123456' WHERE id = '0'

Comment: the above one was the output of the script in update.php doing what you said

Comment: i got it partialy working @VibhaJ i have a new problem with it i made a new topic go to my profile to find it

Answer (score 0):

Could you check on edit.php if $id is actually set to some value instead of empty? Might be that the id is never stored in the session

Comment: i have no clue what you just said

Comment: As per @Yogesh Suthar suggestion, try to print out the value of variable $id or view source to see the form and check what's the $id value in the form

Comment: value is uptop in the edit.php script down towards the bottom

Comment: What do you get if you view source of edit.php in web browser? Especially the section of the form tag -> <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$id;?>">

Comment: the script is Way to long to post here heres my sites link http://fni.site11.com/edit.php @andypp

Answer (score 0):

Right now your $id is null. (int)$id is 0.
So when you try to update WHERE id=$id you are basically saying WHERE id=0
If id is an Auto Increment Integer then you are not going to have an id=0 and nothing will be updated. You need to create the $_SESSION['id'] by putting something in it.
    $_SESSION['id'] = XXXX;

Comment: Im not sure why you are ignoring my answer, but you need a value for $id. If you somehow can find the id, maybe by comparing IP addresses (?) then you can initiate the session by querying the id first. But you cannot update a row of information based on an empty variable, e.g. $id...

Comment: sorry i ignored you i was trying things i have this question in yahoo answers also they dont know what there talking about they said some crazy stuff lol sorry ill try yours hold on

Comment: it didnt work maby i didnt make the script right could you make a copy if mine above for me and edit it

Comment: Just add $_SESSION['id'] = '1'; above $id = $_SESSION['id']; and try it out.

Comment: Above. You still need the $id variable because it is in your query. But I am starting to wonder if you are trying to edit user accounts or create them?

Comment: thats what i got from it this time the user i am logged in as is an user with the id 9 and i dont understand that...

Answer (score 0):

```html
$sqlshow =@ mysqli_query($con,"SELECT `id`, `Registration_No`, `First_Name`, `Middle_Name`, `Sir_Name`, `Sex`, `Birth_Day`, `Email`, `Address`, `Phone` FROM `cdtistudent` WHERE id=40"); while($row = @mysqli_fetch_object($sqlshow)) {
```

```html
update.php page

if(isset($_POST["update"])){
 
 $Registration = $_POST['Registration'];
 $First_Name = $_POST['First'];
 $Middle_Name = $_POST['Middle'];
 $Sir_Name = $_POST['Sir'];
 $Sex = $_POST['Sex'];
 $Birth_Day = $_POST['Birth'];
 $Email = $_POST['Email'];
 $Address = $_POST['Address'];
 $Phone=$_POST['Phone'];
 $id=$_POST['id'];
 
 
 $sqlupdate =mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE  cdtistudent
 SET 
 Registration_No='$Registration',
 First_Name='$First_Name',
 Middle_Name='$Middle_Name',
 Sir_Name='$Sir_Name',
 Sex='$Sex',
 Birth_Day='$Birth_Day',
 Email='$Email',
 Address='$Address',
 Phone='$Phone'
 WHERE id='$id'");
 
 if($sqlupdate  === false){
   
   die("".mysqli_error($con));

 
}}
```

it look like
UPDATE `cdtistudent` SET `id`=[value-1],`Registration_No`=[value-2]
,`First_Name`=[value-3],`Middle_Name`=[value-4],`Sir_Name`=[value-5],
`Sex`=[value-6],`Birth_Day`=[value-7],`Email`=[value-8],`Address`=[value-9],`Phone`=[value-10] WHERE id=?;

and edit.php page

```html
$sqlshow =@ mysqli_query($con,"SELECT `id`, `Registration_No`, `First_Name`, `Middle_Name`, `Sir_Name`, `Sex`, `Birth_Day`, `Email`, `Address`, `Phone` FROM `cdtistudent`
                WHERE id=40");
 
 while($row = @mysqli_fetch_object($sqlshow))
 {
```